# pywinauto - dynamic control always listed in print_control_identifiers()

Tags: pywinauto

I'm trying to automate a program that connects and disconnects from the internet. Therefore, in one window it has a dynamic Disconnect button, that only appears when the app is connected.

I'm trying to check for that Disconnect button using the `.exists()` method or the `.visible` param. Unfortunately, both always returns `true` even when the button does NOT exist in the window.

When I check `print_control_identifiers()` the Disconnect button is always listed in that one specific window, although it currently does not exist in the window.

How can I check if the Disconnect button currently exists and/or is visible ?

I'm creating a pywinauto instance using `backend="win32"` as our code was written for these access identifiers and everything else works.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, had a small typo and had to wrap the condition that uses the `.visible` property in a try/except clause as it throws an Exception when the element is not visible... no idea why this does not simply return False, since it is a boolean that returns True when visible.